# when will gnucash 3.8 turn up in the ubuntu repos?

Tags: gnucash

My ubuntu is Linux kubuntu 5.3.0-40-generic

and via apt update I still get

gnucash Build ID: 3.7+(2019-09-07)

It's online banking tool is not compatible with the new crypto procedures of German banks.

Answer (score 1):

From https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnucash:

> focal (gnome): personal and small-business financial-accounting software [universe]
>   1:**3.8**b-1build3: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x

So you'll get it when Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is released in late April 2020, tentatively on [April 23](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule).

Alternatively, if you don't mind using a ppa in 19.10, search [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) for *gnucash ppa*. One example is https://launchpad.net/~sicklylife/+archive/ubuntu/gnucash?field.series_filter=eoan.

Answer (score 0):

2020-04-20 - GnuCash official version is still missing from Ubuntu Software centre for Ubunutu 20.04, there is a branched version which appears to be of older with less functionality.
However GnuCash 3.8 is available in Kubuntu 20.04 software centre.
Kubuntu 20.04; KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5; Kernel version: 5.4.0-37-generic OS: 64 bit

Comment: This is unclear, both Ubuntu and Kubuntu have access to the same software repositories. And consider writing a single answer to a single question

Comment: Yes I don't understand why GnuCash official version could not be seen on Ubuntu software repository. Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit) software centre only showed gnucash-jz. Kubuntu 20.04 show the official version as well as -jz. I have replaced ubuntu with Kubuntu - cannot retry its software centre.